# Ubuntu is running slow

Tags: ubuntu, performance

I'm not sure since when it became slow, but I think after I did `apt-get update`.
Here's my machine details:
[image]

I can see from the system monitor that the CPU is working hard specially when I run Chrome or Firefox:
[image]

here's my TOP snapshot, I was watching youtube on chrome.
sometimes the Xorg will takes 90% of the CPU.

[image]

Comment: Look at the "processes" tab, order by percent CPU.

Comment: if possible put the output of `top` command

Comment: Have you asked at http://askubuntu.com/?as=1?

Comment: `apt-get update` only downloads and refreshes the package cache. Without performing an upgrade no real changes are made to your system. As mentioned you need to look at processes in use and you also need to see how much filesystem space is left. Browsers can cache quite a bit of data. One needs to keep filesystem space used below 90%

Comment: @sergut please don't recommend that users [cross-post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068/203101). This question is perfectly on topic here.

Comment: @bdowning It was the problem before and I deleted most of my file and now I have space below 90%

Answer (score 1):

So, the output of `top` which you've added shows what's going on, and is in general what you should look at when you wonder what's slow.

The top of the screen shows some overall system info — including the *load average*, which gives a sense of system use over the past 1, 5, and 15 minutes (in that order). If the number is about equal to the number of CPU cores on your system, the system is busy but keeping up; higher than that means overloaded.

Below that (below the reverse-background white bar), top
processes in order (by default) of CPU consumption, and so if there's something constantly at the top of that, it's probably to blame. Don't worry so much about the priority and memory numbers in the first few colums — look at %CPU.

In your case, clearly thee top processes are Chrome. Is it stuck? Try closing that program and see if it goes away and the load goes down. If not, kill the process — press `k` in `top`.

Comment: I have tried to close chrome, it's become more faster but everytime I open youtube on my chrome or I plays video on VLC it always happen, what do you think should I do?

Comment: Any pages open in Chrome that use Flash eat CPU like a hungry dog.  I'd bet that's what's happening

Answer (score 0):

The answer is my CPU is overheat.

Comment: This is probably a *symptom*, not an answer.